# How to Access Linux Files in a WSL distro from Windows 10?

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, explorer

Recently I updated my Windows 10 Pro with May Update (version 1903, build 18362.116). Then for my existing distros: OpenSuse Leap 15 and Ubuntu (installed from MS Store), I wanted to open a linux directory by using Explorer and I'm getting this message:

```
[susedis@mypc ~]$ explorer.exe .
If 'explorer.exe' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it, like this:
    cnf explorer.exe
```

This problem happens also with **VSC** (`code`) and **VSC-Insiders** (`code-insiders`).

I've read [this article](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/127857-access-wsl-linux-files-windows-10-a.html) and ...

OPTION 1: my current problem

OPTION 2: icon LINUX does not exist in tree view

OPTION 3: it works

Supposedly options 1 and 2 should exist and work, even more with the latest update. What's wrong? Thanks in advance.

**PS1:** I've found these articles [Run Visual Studio Code for Linux from WSL](https://gist.github.com/fedme/604c6b811939468fdad06e3fbba942ed) and [Using Visual Studio Code with Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://shunsvineyard.info/2019/01/27/using-visual-studio-code-with-windows-subsystem-for-linux/), they talk about installing xserver and more stuff on side linux. But many other articles and videos don't talk about it, it's like it was a built-in feature of Windows. This is so dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found what is the root of my problem: the distro.

<strike>`explorer`, `code`, `code-insiders` commands ONLY work through UBUNTU and I was using OpenSuse.</strike>

This **warning** is lacking in every article on Web I read, including on VSC site (example: [Developing in WSL](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl)). This is a disadvantage for other distros. Very bad.

**PS1**: The solution can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4243).

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and the command "explorer" does not work here either. I am prompted to install jxplorer. Have you gotten it to work in Ubuntu? Is your WSL running as version1 or version2 ? Mine is running WSL2.

Comment: I use WSL1 and "explorer" was working OK, now it shows same error like yours. I've reported this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4243

Comment: You can run Explorer in Ubuntu typing "explorer.exe ." (without quotation marks)