# Accessing Linux files from Windows (host) Explorer

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have just installed WSL with Ubuntu 18.04. I am running Windows 10 Pro on inside track with version 18922.rs_prerelease.190614-1427

I used this guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Then I converted the WLS to WSL2 using this guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-index

PS correctly shows my distro running in WSL2:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl --list --verbose
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-18.04    Running         2
```

I am using git on the distro and have created new SSH-keys. I need to access the key files (at least to copy them) from Windows.

I thought I could write

```
$explorer .
```

as described here:

https://winaero.com/blog/access-wsl-linux-files-file-explorer-windows-10/

And there is no "Tux icon" in my "Networks section" as described here:

https://winaero.com/blog/windows-10-build-18836-shows-wsl-linux-file-system-in-file-explorer/

So what do I do ... how do I access the files from Windows?

Comment: This isn't a programming question. It belongs on Super User.

Comment: Yeah, I realize this ... but Microsoft themselves encourage users to come to this site with this tag (WSL) to get help using WSL(2). I kind of assumed that it would be OK then :-). I found the answer over here, btw: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56334461/how-to-access-linux-files-in-a-wsl-distro-from-windows-10/56363965?noredirect=1#comment100175988_56363965

Comment: The intent with that was to facilitate programming questions with WSL integration.

Answer (score 2):

As described in https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/127857-access-wsl-linux-files-windows-10-a.html access of the linux files is available through `\\wsl$`.

To access to your root distro you could use :

```
explorer \\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04
```

Answer (score 0):

Typing `explorer.exe .` in your Bash shell might work for you as well.